# Strange fs.readFile behavior while testing CoffeeScript with Mocha/Chai

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js, fs, chai

Please consider I have the following CoffeeScript code:

```
class Foobar
    test: (path) ->
        fs = require 'fs'
        fs.readFile path, (err, data) ->
            console.log 'fs.readFile callback fired'

root = exports ? window
root.Foobar = Foobar
```

And the following test file for Mocha:

```
chai = require 'chai'
expect = chai.expect
chai.should()

{Foobar} = require '../source/foobar'

describe 'Foobar', ->
    foobar = null
    it 'does nothing', ->
        foobar = new Foobar
        foobar.test 'foobar.txt'
```

I run the test:

```
mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script -R spec
```

Strangely for me console logs nothing. When I change my Coffee to this (added two lines at the end):

```
class Foobar
    test: (path) ->
        fs = require 'fs'
        fs.readFile path, (err, data) ->
            console.log 'fs.readFile callback fired'

root = exports ? window
root.Foobar = Foobar

foobar = new Foobar
foobar.test 'foobar.txt'
```

I run the test, and now console logs `fs.readFile callback fired` twice, as expected.

So, why console was empty in the first case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that your tests are ending before the `readFile` callback is executed.  The `test` method should accept a callback:

```
class Foobar
    test: (path, callback) ->
        fs.readFile path, (err, data) ->
            console.log 'fs.readFile callback fired'
            callback err, data
```

That way you can write your test to run asynchronously:

```
it 'calls callback', (done) ->
    foobar = new Foobar()
    foobar.test 'foobar.txt', done
```